# Split number 12 into two addendes so that the two addends squared are the biggest

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the following problem;

> Split number 12 into two addendes so that the two addends squared are
>   the biggest.

I think I have to form a function somehow and calculate the derivative, but I am not sure how should the function look.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like $12 = 4+8$ and $4^2 + 8^2 = 80$ and you want to make that as big as possible?

Comment: @Arthur yes, exactly

Comment: Hint: If you make $12=a+b$ then the sum of the squares is $f(a) = a^2 + (12-a)^2$

Comment: @MattiP. where is $b$?

Comment: I replaced $b$ by $12-a$ in the equation.

Comment: @MattiP. The derivative is always 0, so it's the same regardless what value we choose?

Comment: Do you mean the derivative of $f$? Why do you say that it's equal to zero?

Comment: Should both addends be non-negative?

Comment: Are there restrictions on the addendands? Can you calculate $(-10~000~000) + (10~000~012) = 12$?

Comment: The condition on the summands is vague: Is it the square of the sum, or the sum of the squares, that you're trying to maximize?

Comment: addendes or addends?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easy to solve when you reformulate it like so: Two numbers $a$ and $b$, have a sum of $a+b=12$. What is the maximum value of $a^2+b^2$?

Let's mark $f(a,b) = a^2 +b^2$. The two equations are easy to combine into one when we see that $b=12-a$, and then
$$
\begin{split}
f(a) &= a^2+(12-a)^2 \\ 
&= 2a^2 -24a+144 \\
\end{split}
$$
This is a second degree polynomial with a positive coefficient of the term with power two. Therefore, it represents a parabola that opens up "upwards". Therefore, unless **the value of $a$ is restricted, it doesn't have a maximum value**.

If the values of the addendands is limited to positive integers, this means that we must apply the condition
$$
0 \leq a \leq 12
$$
In this case, the the maximum value of $f(a)$ is obtained at the edge of the defined limits.